# Expected onClick listener to be a function, instead got type object - react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

As explained in the title, I am getting the error
Expected onClick listener to be a function, instead got type object

But I am unable to understand why this isnt working.
as far as I know, the onClick listener IS a function.

Here's, the CharacterList Component where the error comes from

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {addCharacterById} from '../actions';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';


class CharacterList extends Component{

    render(){
        //console.log('name : ',this.props.characters[2].name);
        return(
            <div>
            <h3>Characters</h3>
        <ul>
        {this.props.characters.map((character)=>{
            return(<li key={character.id}>{character.name}
                <div
                onClick={this.props.addCharacterById(character.id)}
                >+</div>
                </li>);
        })}
        </ul>
            </div>

            )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        characters:state
    }
}




export default connect(mapStateToProps,{addCharacterById})(CharacterList);
```

And here's the action creator

```
export const ADD_CHARACTER='ADD_CHARACTER';
export function addCharacterById(id){
    var action ={
        type:ADD_CHARACTER,
            id
        }
        return action;

}
```

So, what do you guys think?
what is the problem here?

Comment: "as far as I know, the onClick listener IS a function." Are you sure about that? `console.log` is a function. Is `console.log("Hello")` a function?

Comment: where do you see the console.log("hello")??

Comment: It was an analogy. `this.props.addCharacterById` is a function.
Is `this.props.addCharacterById(character.id)` a function?

Comment: umm, that's a function call!
so, that's what's wrong?

Comment: A function call is not a function. A function call returns a value. You're not passing a function as the `onClick` prop. You're passing the value returned by the function.

Comment: hmm,yeah.
read the other answers too, saying the same thing.
I think I get it now.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The problem is that you're invoking the function immediately and then what's left is the return value, which might not be a function!

What you can do instead is wrap that function call inside an arrow function to solve your problem. It'll call the inner function once you onClick:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {addCharacterById} from '../actions';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';


class CharacterList extends Component{

    render(){
        //console.log('name : ',this.props.characters[2].name);
        return(
            <div>
            <h3>Characters</h3>
        <ul>
        {this.props.characters.map((character)=>{
            return(<li key={character.id}>{character.name}
                <div
                onClick={() => this.props.addCharacterById(character.id)}
                >+</div>
                </li>);
        })}
        </ul>
            </div>

            )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        characters:state
    }
}




export default connect(mapStateToProps,{addCharacterById})(CharacterList);
```

There's diferent ways of doing this, you could for example bind the parameter to the function, like:

```
{this.props.characters.map((character)=>{
    return(<li key={character.id}>{character.name}
        <div
        onClick={this.props.addCharacterById.bind(null, character.id)}
        >+</div>
        </li>);
})}
```

Just shared as an example, so that you understand what's going on and why the first approach is more readable. You may want to look into why .bind in render is a bad practice by reading the article `https://ryanfunduk.com/articles/never-bind-in-render/`

Comment: are not inline functions bad for performance? U r using inline func: ```onClick={() => this.props.addCharacterById(character.id)}```. Funct and obj are reference type, so every time you re-render the app, every func inside render() method will be recreated with a different spot in the memory. If this is true, please tell me why you showed the example with inline func?

Comment: Hi @dragon, all my answers in SO are kept simple, clear and helpful. Performance and optimization are a different topic, don't think at the time the user asked the question understood the issue, so let's also respect that. Once the OP understands the whys/hows it's a simple matter of reading one of the billion articles about this, including the original React documentation that extends it. Here's a nice article about it ( https://flexport.engineering/ending-the-debate-on-inline-functions-in-react-8c03fabd144 ).

Answer (score 13):

`onClick={this.props.addCharacterById(character.id)}` this part of your code will execute immediately upon `render()` is call what you may want to do instead is:

`onClick={(e)=> {this.props.addCharacterById(e, character.id)}}`

Remember the first parameter pass to `onClick` is the click event.

Answer (score 8):

Don't directly call functions in `onClick` event. It will recursively call the method. So make the `onClick` input as a callback method.

Change this line

```
onClick={this.props.addCharacterById(character.id)}
```

to

```
onClick={() => this.props.addCharacterById(character.id)}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are some things that you need to change if you want to have good practices.

First, add `mapDispatchToProps` function.

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
...
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    addCharacterById: bindActionCreators(addCharacterById, dispatch)
  };
}
```

Second, the event handler could be:

```
onClick={() => this.props.addCharacterById(character.id)}
```

Third, export your component:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CharacterList);
```

Comment: could you explain why you are using the bindActionCreators the way you did, instead of this below:

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
 bindActionCreators({addCharacterById},dispatch);
}

and which one is better?

Comment: @faraz I put bindActionCreators function in my answer because you have it in your example but really it is not necessary.
The only use case for bindActionCreators is when you want to pass some action creators down to a component that isn't aware of Redux, and you don't want to pass dispatch or the Redux store to it.

Answer (score 1):

Just an additional answer, make sure that all the onClick on your code has this kind of format.

```
onClick={() => this.props.addCharacterById(character.id)}
```

Even if one onClick has a format like this **onClick={this.props.addCharacterById(character.id)}** it can be problematic